# What would climates look like on a world 1°C?

Tags: science-based, climate

I am creating a world that is very cold (average of 1°C) and when I got to making the climates, I didn’t know what to do since the only climate tutorials I could find were for worlds around Earth’s temperature, not for very cold worlds. How would the climates on my planet differ from Earth?

Other Information about planet:
Spins retrograde,
Completes a full rotation every 67 hours,
Average temperature at equator is 1 °C,
The total albedo is 40%,
The planet has a 1.01 AU orbit,
The planet has an axial tilt of 4°,

Comment: Is everything else the same as Earth?  Size, water, solar energy etc?

Comment: There are a lot of other contributing variables to climate besides average global temperature can you [edit] this post to include a more detailed description of your world?

Comment: @sphennings what other things should I include?

Comment: @Willk the surface is 64% water and the size is the same

Comment: [Anders Celsius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anders_Celsius) wonders why you have downgraded the initial of his name to lower case. (And a degree Celsius is a unit of measurement, so there should be a space between 1 and °C.) (As for the question, the climate would be *very* different. Huge ice caps. Very much less precipitation.)

Comment: @AlexP If you tab-complete my name it will be lowercase.

Comment: Are you asking for global climate (this would need more information about the planet in general) or some specific area (in addition to the information about the planet that would need information about the geography of this particular area)? Could you edit your question to include the necessary information?

Comment: If you want us to use Earth as a point of departure use the earthlike tag otherwise we need to know a lot more about this world.

Comment: What other information should I add?

Comment: You might want to investigate [Snowball Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowball_Earth).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Bring down the polar regions.**

[image: ice sheet]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurentide_Ice_Sheet

Earth used to be colder.  Take the changes that occurred during the last glacial maximum and make them more extreme.

> The average global temperature during the period known as the Last
> Glacial Maximum from roughly 23,000 to 19,000 years ago was about 46
> degrees Fahrenheit (7.8 degrees Celsius), some 13 degrees Fahrenheit
> (7 Celsius) colder than 2019, the researchers said.
>
> Certain regions were much cooler than the global average, they found.
> The polar regions cooled far more than the tropics, with the Arctic
> region 25 degrees Fahrenheit (14 degree Celsius) colder than the
> global average.

During periods of cooling and [also warming](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/220954/what-would-the-equator-be-like-if-modern-day-earth-were-as-hot-as-the-cambrian), changes are more extreme at the poles than closer to the equator.  The equator does not change much.  Average global temperature changes are driven mostly by changes in average temperature at very high latitudes.

You can achieve your 0C average by extrapolating the ice age to more southerly latitudes.

If this is just Earth, colder, then colder also means drier for most places where the average temperature does not change as much.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Glacial_Maximum

> The Amazon rainforest was split into two large blocks by extensive
> savanna, and the tropical rainforests of Southeast Asia probably were
> similarly affected, with deciduous forests expanding in their place
> except on the east and west extremities of the Sundaland shelf. Only
> in Central America and the Chocó region of Colombia did tropical
> rainforests remain substantially intact – probably due to the
> extraordinarily heavy rainfall of these regions.
>
> A map of vegetation patterns during the last glacial maximum. Most of
> the world's deserts expanded...
>
> In Australia, shifting sand dunes covered half the continent, while
> the Chaco and Pampas in South America became similarly dry.
> Present-day subtropical regions also lost most of their forest cover,
> notably in eastern Australia, the Atlantic Forest of Brazil, and
> southern China, where open woodland became dominant due to drier
> conditions. In northern China – unglaciated despite its cold climate –
> a mixture of grassland and tundra prevailed, and even here, the
> northern limit of tree growth was at least 20° farther south than
> today.